# Angular, how to subscribe to a specific data from JSON?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a little question.

I am trying to subscribe to a specific key from my json. For example my json is like;
{
"title": "Basketball",
"game_type": "Ball Game",
"platform": "Court"
},
{
"title": "Football",
"game_type": "Ball Game",
"platform": "Grass"
}...
And it keeps going on like this for about 100 different keys. What I want is, to subscribe only to the key with the title "Basketball", so that I can print to browser only that.

Here is my service look like;

```
import { Games} from '../game/Games';
import { GameKeys } from '../game_key/GameKeys';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SelectedGameService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  keys = "http://localhost:3000/GameKeys"; //MY JSON LINK AT COMPUTER

  getKeys():Observable<GameKeys[]> {   //HERE I RETURN THE KEYS IN MY JSON
    return this.http.get<GameKeys[]>(this.keys);
  }
}
```

Here is my component of where I want to subscribe;

```
    gKeys : Games[];   //THE ELEMENT THAT I WANT TO FILL
        ngOnInit() {    
            this.selectedGameService.getKeys().subscribe(data=>{  //HERE I SUBS TO DATA
              this.gKeys = data;
             /*WHAT I WANT IS TO LET THIS "gKeys" ELEMENT TO BE SUBSCRIBED ONLY TO THE 
             KEY THAT HAS THE TITTLE "BASKETBALL"*/
        })        
      }
    }
```

So eventually in the end, I will only press the key that has basketball in its tittle. But I don't want to use pipe either.

How will I suppuse to do that?
Thank you from now for your helps :)

Comment: If you just want to show it on your page you absolutely don't need to subscribe to a specific key. Just get your data and print just the key you want, or, separate it in another variable if needed.

Comment: Any specific reason not want to use pipe ?

Comment: Naah @QuentinGrisel, I believe he's may be looking to extract via title:basketball

Comment: @Akhil Still doen't make sense to me, a simple condition and another variable is enough

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer. Why I said that I dont want to use pipe is that there will be thousands of keys in later, wouldn't doing pipe make my code run slower? This might be a dummy question since I am new to Angular :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you need a `map` RxJS operator, and the `filter` on the arrays, more or less like this:

```
isBasketball = (item: GameKeys): boolean => item.title === 'Basketball';

keepOnlyBasketballs = (items: GameKeys[]): Gamekeys[] => items.filter(this.isBasketball);

getBasketballKeys = (): Observable<GameKeys[]) => this.selectedGameService.getKeys()
    .pipe(map(this.keepOnlyBasketballs));
```

Comment: Yep.. This would help. But, the question says he dont wants to use pipe. I am just trying to understand why he dont wants pipe since using them actually makes life easier when dealing with  streams

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your answer. Why I said that I dont want to use pipe is that there will be thousands of keys in later, wouldn't doing pipe make my code run slower? This might be a dummy question since I am new to Angular :/